# Where to find the git remote username in local config?

Tags: git

I forgot what my `git` remote username was that I used to clone the remote to local many months ago.  Now I need to set up another local environment and need to clone it using my username.  How do I find the username the local clone was set up under in the `.git` configuration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you used that login in the clone url, like

```
git clone https://user@github.com/user/repo.git
```

you may look at output of

```
git remote -v show
```

If you didn't supply it that way, but typed it in server prompt and you don't have any keyring set up, then I suppose there is no way to do it.